# Problems during the transfer of PDF files from client to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have implemented a client-server transferring from Windows desktop application to iPhone App. I transfer data in a different format but always as a string using NSStream polling mode:

```
    if([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (len > 0) {
            NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            if (nil != output) {
                [_arrRisposta addObject:output];
                _strRisposta = [NSMutableString stringWithString: output];
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, but when I transfer a PDF file and save it, the file is not the same. When I load the file in UIWebView the number of pages is correct but there is no content. I save the file like this:

```
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *dataFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.%@", @"pdf"]];

                if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataFile]) {
                    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dataFile error:nil];
                }
                [_strContenuto writeToFile:dataFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

                NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataFile];
                [webModello loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl]];
```

What's wrong? I tried to change the encoding of the string but I have not solved. If I compare the transferred file with the original, there are some characters that do not match.
Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use strings. Change your code to use NSData objects. PDF files are not strings, and there are all sorts of encoding issues you would have to worry about to get this working with strings (if it ever would).

I have not looked up the exact api usage for NSData, this is all from my head... so don't go copy and pasting this!

```
// Somewhere in your code
 _myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// when data comes in....

 if([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
    if (len > 0) {
           [_myData addBytes:buffer length:len];
        }
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

// when the callback comes in saying all data  there:
 [_myData writeToFile:@"path/topdf/file.pdf" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you Tom but, I can not use NSData to this point in my work. The strings that I receive have a header and a tail that delimit the content (eg <TOK> ....</ TOKm>).
I extract the string that interests me, then process it. In the case of PDF (eg <TOK format='pdf'>%PDF-1.4 %Çì¢ 5 0 obj <</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>> ... startxref 3114 %%EOF</TOKm>), save it as a file and open it in the UIWebView.
I am forced to use strings. How can I do?

Comment: You are going to have to use the smallest, simplest PDF you can find. Say its 1952 bytes long on the server. Then it needs to be exactly 1952 bytes long when you resurrect it. There could be url like encoding, or xml encoding, etc happening. If you have no control over the server, and 'know the server works' cause there are other clients - then that's half the battle won. Once you get the byte lengths the same, it still might not work, though. If you have control on the server side too, I would transmit the pdf as a base64 encoded string, then decode that in the client. That will work.

Comment: Another point - I see you use NSUTF8StringEncoding when writing and ASCII when loading the data in. If you are trying to fool NSString - then stick to ascii everywhere, I would think.

Comment: Solved with Base64 encoded/decoded. Thank you very much, Tom!